# "Uncombine" Paths in Fireworks?

Tags: vector, adobe-fireworks

Is there a way to undo combining paths in Adobe Fireworks? Or is it permanent?

Comment: ctrl+z  to undo.................

Comment: Re. Can you explain this a little bit? Why is ctrl+Z (mentioned in an comment to the question) wrong? ctrl+z only applies if you've made the change (i.e. combined the paths) and you are still running the same application session. You can split combined paths at any time.

Answer (score 2):

Modify>Combine paths>Split
or Split paths from the paths panel

Answer (score 1):

In Fireworks CS5 there is option to use Compound Shape tools for non-desctructive path combining (eg. without going Union Paths via Path Panel).

[This article](http://www.fireworkszone.com/compound-shape-tools-in-fireworks-cs5_592.html) explains how Compound Shape Tools works:

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

(10 characters minimum)

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit? Why is ctrl+Z (mentioned in an comment to the question) wrong?