# Separate composite path wth fireworks?

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I want to paint each path in a different color, so How can I separate this one composite path into 10 different paths?
[image]

How I do it is that I create a path over each section and then "intersect", but I have to do this 10 times. There has to be a simpler way.

[image]

Comment: Select the subpath and hit ctl+ c and paste in new path?

Comment: With FW CS5: Modify>Combine paths>Split https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1466/uncombine-paths-in-fireworks

Comment: I'm a firm believer that "newer is **not** always better" -- but it's tough to support software that was discontinued 8+years ago and simply won't run on most computers purchased in the last 5 years. -- Just guessing... can't use use a "direct selection" tool (usually a white arrow cursor) to select just one path and color it?

Comment: With Fireworks CS5: Modify > Combine paths > Split https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1466/uncombine-paths-in-fireworks

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncombine" Paths in Fireworks?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1466/uncombine-paths-in-fireworks)